# Formal and actual parameters in a function in python

Tags: python, function, recursion, iteration, branch

I'm kind of confused on how to identify the formal and actual parameters in a recursive function. For example in this block of code for getting the factorial of a number:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
       return 1
    else:
       return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Is "factorial(n-1)" the formal parameter since it is inside the function itself? Or is it the actual parameter because it assigned a value for the function. Also, is the "factorial(n)" the formal parameter as well?

Comment: "formal parameter" is a synonym for what is normally labelled "parameter", and "actual parameter" for "argument". Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A formal parameter, i.e. a parameter, is in the *function definition*. An actual parameter, i.e. an argument, is in a *function call*.

So `n` here:

```
def factorial(n):
```

Is a formal parameter.

And `n - 1` (or rather, the *value it evaluates to*) here:

```
   return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Is an "actual parameter", i.e. an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The formal parameter is the *name* you use to refer to the actual parameter (aka argument) to the function. In your definition of `factorial`, `n` is the formal parameter. In the *call* to `factorial`, the *value* of the expression `n - 1` serves as the actual parameter which inside the recursive call is bound to (again) the formal parameter `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The `n` in the `factorial(n)` definition is the formal parameter, as it is the parameter with which the function is being defined. The `n-1` in the `factorial(n-1)` call is an actual parameter, as that is the parameter which the function is being called with.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you defined a [function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) as follow:

- You start the `function` blocks with the keyword `def` followed by the function name and parentheses `()`
- Any input parameters or arguments *should be placed within these parentheses.* You can also define parameters inside these parentheses.

In  the code you provided. the function `factorial` takes a *parameter* `n`. So for example when I call the function `factorial(1+2+3)` the expression `1+2+3` get interpreted and becomes `6` and passed in as the *function argument* to fit *parameter* `n`.

So in your function `factorial` where you called `factorial(n+1)` you are passing in whatever value generate by `n+1` in to `factorial` as the parameter  `n`

Answer (score 0):

when a function is defined, it may have some parameters. These parameters are useful to receive values from outside of the function. They are called 'formal arguments'. When we call the function, we should pass data or values to the function. These values are called 'actual arguments'. 
In the following code, 'a' and 'b' are formal arguments and 'x' and 'y' are actual arguments.

```
def sum(a, b): #a, b are formal arguments
    c = a+b 
    print(c)

#call the function 
x = 10; y = 15
sum(x, y) #x, y are actual arguments
```