# Can someone explain the reason behind the Actual and Formal Parameters in this code

Tags: python, parameters

So I am following some guides/lessons someone else has made and come across the discussion of formal and actual parameters.

When looking at this code (below) I see that the function definition has some arguments that pass in a variable(is that right?) as f_amount for example, but then in the function itself it does not use f_amount, just amount.

Secondly, when the function is called, two variables are setup and ready to receive the return values from the function, but my question is, why is it passing in the two variables when I could just remove the parameters from the function definition and the call and it would still perform the same output?

```
def getBankDetails(f_amount, f_rate):
    print("Please enter the amount you have in the bank: ")
    amount = float(input())
    print("Please enter interest rate: ")
    rate = float(input())
    print(amount, rate)
    return amount, rate

def calculateInterest(f_amount, f_rate, f_interest):
    interest = amount / rate
    return interest

def displayInterest(f_interest):
    print("You have earned £", interest, "in interest this year")

amount = 0.0
rate = 0.0
interest = 0.0

amount, rate = getBankDetails(amount, rate)
interest = calculateInterest(amount, rate, interest)
displayInterest(interest)
```

vs

```
def getBankDetails():
    print("Please enter the amount you have in the bank: ")
    amount = float(input())
    print("Please enter interest rate: ")
    rate = float(input())
    print(amount, rate)
    return amount, rate

def calculateInterest():
    interest = amount / rate
    return interest

def displayInterest():
    print("You have earned £", interest, "in interest this year")

amount, rate = getBankDetails()
interest = calculateInterest()
displayInterest()
```

Comment: Yes, I don't see why you would need to send parameters with that approach. The second version is cleaner. However, in your `calculateInterest()`, you will not have access to `amount` and `rate` unless you pass them as parameters.

Comment: @khelwood I have edited it so that the indentation is correct.

Comment: I think the following link might help you understand in a more clearer way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065288/formal-and-actual-parameters-in-a-function-in-python

Comment: @AnoopRDesai - My thinking is that it was done this way to explain Formal and Actual parameters? Also, the code in the second version works fine - it will calculate the interest rate and output it.

Comment: I see why it would work in this case - because the same names `amount` and `rate` are used both within and outside the function. However, this is not recommended and gets hard to maintain as the code grows.